# Failing to install pandas due to an error

Tags: python-3.7

I am Failing to install pandas in cmd using `pip-install pandas` due to the error below that pops up when installing. I am using python version 3.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 360, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 447, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 491, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 334, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 878, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 702, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 946, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 639, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py", line 62, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 607, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 596, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 494, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 459, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\chiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 365, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I tried updating pip with the command `pip install -U pip setuptools`
but it showed that pip is up to date.
I tried again `pip install fbchat` which downloaded successfully but after trying to install pandas with the same "pip install pandas" the error popped up again.**

Comment: [Read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70883/how-do-i-install-python-pandas). And welcome to So: [Read this to understand how to post questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)